# Prevent list addition based on size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to limit the `grab` command to only allow 4 items to be in the list at a time as well as for the `drop` and `edit` command. I'm trying to add a message that would say `invalid` if the user enters any number of items that is an invalid number.

```
  def grab(item_list):
       item = input("Name: ")
       item_list.append(item)
       print(item + " was added.\n")


   def edit(item_list):
       pos = int(input("Number: "))    
       new_value = input("Updated name: ")
       item_list[pos-1] = new_value
       print("%s was updated" % (new_value))

   def drop(item_list):
       number = int(input("Number: "))
       item = item_list.pop(number-1)
       print(item + " was dropped.\n")
       print()

   def main():
       item_list = ["wooden staff","wizard hat","cloth shoes"]
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How I incoprate a invalid message for drop and edit functions when the user selects a item number that’s not on list.

Comment: For example if I wrote number:5 then it should display an error message saying invalid number or such @Julien

Comment: Did you try adding a simple if statement checking the length before you add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   def grab(item_list):
       if len(item_list)==4:
           print('Cannot grab more than 4. Drop another item and try again')
           return
       item = input("Name: ")
       item_list.append(item)
       print(item + " was added.\n")


   def edit(item_list):
       pos = int(input("Number: "))
       if not (pos-1)in range(len(item_list)):
           print(str(pos) + ' not in list, try again')
           edit(item_list)
           return
       new_value = input("Updated name: ")
       item_list[pos-1] = new_value
       print("Updated item %d with new value %s" % (pos, new_value))

   def drop(item_list):
       number = int(input("Number: "))
       if not (number-1) in range(len(item_list)):
           print(str(number) + ' not in list, try again')
           drop(item_list)
           return
       item = item_list.pop(number-1)
       print(item + " was dropped.\n")
       print()
```

Comment: line 34, in edit
    print(pos + ' not in list, try again')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'                                           when I input 5 for the edit and drop functions it gives me the error messages above. the grab function works well @julien

Comment: Does the edited version work? Let me know of any errors you are facing. Otherwise accept as answer, thx!

Comment: def edit(item_list):
       pos = int(input("Number: "))
       if not (pos-1)in range(len(item_list)):
           print(str(pos) + ' not in list, try again')
           edit(item_list)
           return
       new_value = input("Updated name: ")
       item_list[pos-1] = new_value
       print("%s was updated" % (new_value))                                                         Yes it does work. I was wondering how i would get it to display item number was updated. Ive tried but i keep getting an error

Comment: no the edit works fine! but i was wondering how i could get it to print item and then the number was updated.

Comment: Updated code to show what you need. Please do review and re-use in the other function as well.

Comment: im sorry but im not understanding the functions you're using. I need it to be displayed as lets say user picked item 1 then it would print  (item 1 was updated).

Comment: `print("Updated item %d with new value %s" % (pos, new_value))` This prints the string between quotes by replacing `%d` & `%s` with values in `pos` & `new_value`

Comment: The order of the format notations of `%d` (to print an int at this position) `%s` (to print a string at this position) should match with the data types of variables `pos` (int) and `new_value` (string)

Comment: Do you strictly need to show only `item 1 was updated`? If so then use `print('item %d was updated'%(pos))`

Comment: Yes it does @bulbus . Thank you!